# How to make a text box active(Similar to rename by F2) in blender python?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, properties, panel

I have a panel that pops up when a user presses some shortcut key and the panel has one text box(row.prop(....)).Now i want to make the text box active so that when the user presses the shortcut key to open the panel they can start typing straight away without having to manually click the text box. Similar to what to you get when you press F2 to rename an object and you dont have to click the text box to write its already active by default.